# How do I can to resolve this error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework in C#, I get this error:

> The entry 'AlMizanEntities' has already been added.
>   (D:\Document\Almizan\AlMizan\C#\AlMizan\bin\Debug\AlMizan.vshost.exe.config
>   line 7)

My code:

```
private void Fraz()
{
    label1.Text = "Fraz ...";
    Application.DoEvents();

    AlMizanEntities1 ObjAE = new AlMizanEntities1();
}

public partial class AlMizanEntities1 : ObjectContext
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Initializes a new AlMizanEntities1 object using the connection string found in the 'AlMizanEntities1' section of the application configuration file.
   /// </summary>
   // *ERROR* occurs here
   public AlMizanEntities1() : base("name=AlMizanEntities1", "AlMizanEntities1")
   {
      this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
      OnContextCreated();
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Initialize a new AlMizanEntities1 object.
   /// </summary>
   public AlMizanEntities1(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "AlMizanEntities1")
   {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Initialize a new AlMizanEntities1 object.
   /// </summary>
   public AlMizanEntities1(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection, "AlMizanEntities1")
   {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
   }
}
```

Comment: you'll need to show some code and a schema. It looks like a unique constraint being violated but that's impossible to tell with out some more information. Aside from the prior mentioned you should supplied some info about the input and the content of the table. Not all just enough to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove `line 7` in `D:\Document\Almizan\AlMizan\C#\AlMizan\App.config`
or remove the duplicated line somewhere else in that file.

Comment: Probably better in `App.config` because `...vshost.exe.config` gets copied from `App.config` when the application is compiled, I believe.